# Maximizing over an integral with a single parameter

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

There is probably a neat approach to solve this problem...but can't get to it at the moment. How do you maximize an integral with respect to a single parameter? My code below produces error messages. Please note I have amended the `Wf[a_,b_]` to a simpler form to make it more explicit.

```
 Wf[a_, b1_] := 1/2 Erfc[(-a + 0.1)/(Sqrt[2] b1)]


 Wfunc[al_, r_, s1_, s2_, m_] := 
 16*(Wf[s1*Sqrt[4 + (2*al*r*m)^2], s2]/(1 + (al*r*m)^2)^(3/2) - 
     Wf[s1*Sqrt[4 + (2*al*r*(1 - m))^2], 
       s2]/(1 + (al*r*(1 - m))^2)^(3/2))^2 

ListPlot[Table[{rm, 
   NIntegrate[
    y^2*Wfunc[y, rm, 0.015, 0.005, 0.71], {y, 0.01, 5}]}, {rm, 0.01, 
   2, 0.01}]]

 Maximize[
 NIntegrate[y^2*Wfunc[y, rm, 0.015, 0.005, 0.31], {y, 0.01, 5}], rm]
```

What I want is the value of `rm` that maximizes the Integral in the last line without error msgs.

[image]

```
(*  The integrand 16 y^2 (Erfc[141.421 (0.1 +Times[<<2>>])]/(2 (1+0.0961 Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])^(3/2))-Erfc[141.421 (0.1 +Times[<<2>>])]/(2 (1+0.4761 Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])^(3/2)))^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.01`,5}}. >> *)

(* {0.109851, {rm -> 1.20352}} *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create another function for the integral as

```
int[rm_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[y^2*Wfunc[y, rm, 0.015, 0.005, 0.31], {y, 0.01, 5}]
```

This should prevent any non-numerical arguments getting into Nintegrate. Now we get the following data

```
Table[{rm, int[rm]}, {rm, 0.01, 2, 0.01}]
```

Also

```
In[10]:= NMaximize[int[rm], rm]

Out[10]= {0.109851, {rm -> 1.20352}}
```

Did you get a different rm value by using Maximize ?

Comment: Lotus.........I wonder why  u missed out on the right rm value by a small amt?

Comment: I am surprised myself. Especially since the Maximum value seems to be correct.

Comment: Me too! I wonder what's happening here.

Comment: It was a simple transcription error - you had .71 instead of .31, fixed it for you (hope you don't mind)

Comment: I am glad that this is resolved.

Comment: And that came from the fact that OP used both values in his post, .71 for the graph, and .31 for the `Maximize` call

Answer (score 3):

You got the right answer, but it gave error messages because it tried to evaluate the integral - so take the integral out of the optimization step by building an interpolation function.

```
list = Table[{rm, 
   NIntegrate[
    y^2*Wfunc[y, rm, 0.015, 0.005, 0.31], {y, 0.01, 5}]}, {rm, 0.01, 
   10, 0.01}];
func = Interpolation[list];
Plot[func[x], {x, .1, 9}]
```

[image]

All of these will give the right answer,

```
Maximize[{func[x], 0 < x < 2}, x]
NMaximize[{func[x], 0 < x < 2}, x]
NMaximize[{func[x], 0.5 < x < 10}, x]
FindMaximum[func[x], x]
FindMaximum[func[x], {x, 1}]
(* {0.109851, {x -> 1.20353}} *)
(* {0.109851, {x -> 1.20353}} *)
(* {0.109851, {x -> 1.20353}} *)
(* {0.109851, {x -> 1.20353}} *)
(* {0.109851, {x -> 1.20353}} *)
```

But you have to visually inspect the plot to make sure you don't get the second, local maximum

```
NMaximize[{func[x], 0 < x < 10}, x]
FindMaximum[func[x], {x, 2.1}]
(* {0.104022, {x -> 2.60866}} *)
(* {0.104022, {x -> 2.60866}} *)
```

Comment: +1...let me wait & see if someone comes up with an alternative that does not involve interpolation...

Comment: Yeah, Lotus's method is more correct I reckon, though not any faster than the interpolating method - sometimes I go for the fast and dirty method :-)